# How do I get the subset of a DataFrame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a DataFrame by a date column, where one DataFrame will be those observations that are before a certain date, and the other DataFrame will be those observations that are after that date.

I have some data frame with some columns, where the date column is named 'date_posted'. The data frame is named proj.

I've tried just subsetting it by using the following notation:

```
out_1 = proj[proj.date_posted >= '20140101']
out_2 = proj[proj.date_posted < '20140101']
```

but that does not seem to work. I've also tried using the ix and groupby functions, but I can't seem to get either to work. Is there a function that works similarly to the subset() function in R?

Comment: Does the date column contain strings or actual datetime values?  Did you try using `'2014-01-01'` format instead of `'20140101'`?

Comment: you probably need to convert those strings and your `date_posted` column to `pandas.Timestamp` objects.

Comment: What does running the above code give you: an empty dataframe? the whole dataframe? an error?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, so you likely have trouble with the 'date_posted' column.  Is it a string and not an int?

If its already an int try:

```
out_1 = proj[proj['date_posted'] >= 20140101]
out_2 = proj[proj['date_posted'] < 20140101]
```

If its really a string try converting it first:

```
proj['date_posted'] = proj['date_posted'].apply(int)
out_1 = proj[proj['date_posted'] >= 20140101]
out_2 = proj[proj['date_posted'] < 20140101]
```